# Ajax call run by form submission and will pass data to a separate views.py template

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, ajax

I am building a web application using Django.  I have a search function on my index page.  When a user submits the form an AJAX call should be executed.  This AJAX call should take all the needed data from the form and pass it over to a completely separate views.py template that will make API GET requests using that data and build a new page using that separate template.

As of right now it is not loading the separate views.py template, I am unsure if I am passing the data correctly however I do see `/searchresults?searchType=data1&amp;executeLocation=data2` in my console because my AJAX call is returning on `success` currently.  It is safe to assume that I have all the data needed in the data1 and data2 variables, I just need help redirecting to the new page and passing the data along with the redirect.

My code:

urls.py

```
 # The home page
 path('', views.index, name='home'),
 # Search results page
 path('searchresults', views.search_results, name='searchresults'),
```

AJAX

```
function getSearchResults(searchType,executeLocation,csrf_token) 
{
    $.ajax(
    {
        type: $(this).attr('method'),
        url: "searchresults", //The URL you defined in urls.py
        data : 
        {
            searchType: searchType,
            executeLocation: executeLocation,
            csrfmiddlewaretoken: csrf_token
        },
        dataType: 'text',
        success: function(response) // currently executes success (but not correct outcome)
        {
            console.log(response);
            alert('winner winner chicken dinner');
        },
        error: function(response)
        {
            console.log(response);
            alert('failure');
        }
    }).done(function(data)
    {
        console.log(data)
    });
}
```

index.html

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'searchresults'%}">
...
<button type="submit" onclick="getSearchResults('data1','data2','{{csrf_token}}')">Submit</button>
</form>
```

views.py

```
def search_results(request):
    context = {}
    context['requestData'] = request.POST
    html_template = loader.get_template('search/searchresults.html')
    return HttpResponseRedirect(html_template.render(context, request))
```

An acceptable solution should be able to do the following tasks:

1. Redirect the user to the search_results page
2. Pass the form data to the search_results page somehow

Comment: Ajax is used when you don't want to redirect to other page or don't want to reload the page. When you want to show the result in other page just post the data to that view it doesn't need ajax

Comment: @AminMir Forgive me but I am new to Django.  Could you show me what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After assistance from @AminMir I was able to get a working solution.  It turns out I do not need AJAX but I did need a forms.py file.

view.py

```
def index(request):
    context = {'segment': 'index'}
    context['SearchForm'] = SearchForm()
    return HttpResponse(html_template.render(context, request))
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms

class SearchForm(forms.Form):
    searchType = forms.CharField(max_length = 100)
    executedLocation = forms.CharField(max_length = 100)
    searchValue = forms.CharField(max_length = 100)
```

index.html

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'searchresults'%}">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ SearchForm.as_ul }}
  <input type="submit" value="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

This form will then post my data to my views.py for my search_result page which is left unchanged.